# How to change color of dates on calendar in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I'm trying to change the color of a periode on my calendar here I'm getting the periode from mysql database

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id;
function displayPeriode() {
     id=15;
      var urlString ="id="+id;
      $.ajax
({
      url: "http://localhost/duration.php",
      type : "GET",
      cache : false,
      data : urlString,
      success: function(response){
          //convertir php array to javascript aaray 
          var ar = JSON.parse( response);   
             alert(ar[i]);
                  for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                         alert(ar[i]);
                         return [true, 'markperiod'];}
 } 
      });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="datepicker">
 <div class="datepicker-header"></div>
```

and in css file

```
.markperiod {
background-color:red;
color: white;}
```

I want to color the days of datepicker class in the success function

Comment: Write an extra css rule for it. like : `.datepicker{ color: green; }`, I'm sure there's a class of reference to it that you can use. Or look in the docs of the datepicker plugin, they might even provide you with options to set colors etc.

Comment: the datepicker is a div that contain the calendar and i want to color its period

Comment: Yes, I understand. Add the css rule for it in your stylesheet.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand you

Comment: Add the `.markperiod` class you have in your css, to every element that needs that color. So the colored div becomes something like `<div class="markperiod">`

Comment: Something like: `<html>
<head>
 <style>
 .markperiod {
  background-color:red;
  color: white;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="datepicker">
  <div class="datepicker-header">
   <div class="markperiod">first day</div>
   <div class="markperiod">second day</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: sir i already have a css file but i want to use javascript to color the periode that i've recieve from PHP file on my calendar witch is <div class="datepicker">

Comment: `document.querySelector('.datepicker').className = 'datepicker markperiod';` like this ? Or do you have multiple divs with the class datepicker and you have to find the correct one?

Comment: the script part retrieve the periode of dates, the datepicker div is a calendar witch is prepared in  a separate file